# How to add Label dynamically in textArea?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

i want to add this Label to TextArea but when i run it not show any info. means label info.
i want that whatever info. packet contain will be in Label (jl), and Label will be added to the TextArea1 one by one ..

i can append the text but i don't want that i only want to add label to the TextArea

```
if (captor == null) {
    // open device in promesous mode          
    captor = jpcap.JpcapCaptor.openDevice(pnic, 65535, true, 1000);
    System.out.println("Now device is openned");
}
System.out.println(captor);
moreInfo(nic[PacketSniffer.choice]);

while (main.statu) {
    p = captor.getPacket();
    if (p != null) { 
        javax.swing.JLabel jl = new javax.swing.JLabel(count + ":" + p + "\n");
        jTextArea1.add(jl);
        count++;
    }
}
```

- `captor`: object to open an Interface for packet capturing
- `p`: Packet info that arrive or leave the system

Comment: If you wish to add components to a textual component, use `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane` instead of `JTextArea`, which only supports ..plain text.

Comment: 1) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) Please use code formatting for code, input/output & structured documents like HTML or XML.  To do that, select the sample and click the `{}` button above the messaged posting/editing form.

Comment: alternate are there... but question is that jTextArea allow to add component then why they are not display there??

Comment: *"but question is that jTextArea"*  It is `JTextArea` (3 upper case letters) *"allow to add component"*  No it doesn't.